# rg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for relation food

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, intellij-idea, dropwizard

i have a dropWizard java server application connected to localhost database via Postgresql. i changed config.yaml user and password to my real time server which also works with Postgresql and i made a jar file from build->artifact in Intellij idea and then change it back and after that all the request to my localhost-based face the same Errors (food is one of my model classes):

```
rg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for 
relation food
```

heres my config.yaml :

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
  - type: http
port: 9000
adminConnectors:
- type: http
port: 9001
database:
# the name of your JDBC driver
driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver

# the username
user: *********

# the password
password: **********
 # the JDBC URL
url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/
# any properties specific to your JDBC driver:
properties:
charSet: UTF-8
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate
```

i didn't apply any changes to the project and it has been jammed after that. i had an other copy of the project, unzipped it, deleted the other copy and run the new one and the same errors!

Comment: file -> invalidate cach/restart didn't help? or try rebuilding it..

Comment: nope, did both several times, even restart my computer several time!